# react native : An error while try open date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datepicker

It is not clear for what reason an error is received when activating the date picker.
I would be happy to some help.

The error is:

"value.getTime is not a function. (In 'value.getTime ()', 'value.getTime' is undefined"

**MyDatePicker function**

```
let date1 = useSelector(state => state.DatePickerReducer.date1);
```

**DatePickerReducer**

```
const today = new Date();

const initializeState = {
  date1: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1, 10),
  date2: today.addMonths(1)
};

export default function DatePickerReducer(state = initializeState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_DATE_1:
      return {
        ...state,
        date1: action.payload ? action.payload : state.date1,
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your date object is getting serialized into string.
Try wrapping the **date1** variable in a date object in your **MyDatePicker** function .

```
let dateString= useSelector(state => state.DatePickerReducer.date1); 
let date1 =new Date(dateString);
```

Comment: i need to display the current date..its show me some random date

Comment: Please add the code where you are using datepicker and also the code where you are dispatching SET_DATE_1 action